# I want to create an expression for querystrings, this stuff is hard!

Tags: asp.net, query-string, text-extraction

I want to extract some keywords out of a query string for a search application in asp.net.

I decoded the url string first, so it's plain text

I have this to start with, but I want to add a keyword group

```
([\?\&])q=[^\&]+[\&]?
```

I get this ?q=harbour landing dental&

I'd like to trim off the stuff for pure words, but not sure if that's possible

I also have a long list of possible query string value fields that I want to check against

```
?q=
@q=
?qs=
&qs=
```

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you just use the [HttpRequest.QueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) collection?

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the `HttpRequest` you should just use the [`HttpRequest.QueryString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) property.

If you don't have access to that and only have the actual query string as a string you should just use the [`HttpUtil.ParseQueryString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx) function to get the `NameValueCollection`.